# Run katalon docker on windows

Tags: windows, docker, katalon-studio

I have read this: https://github.com/katalon-studio/docker-images but I seem to have problems with the syntax... Does anyone have an example of a functional line for windows? tnx in advance

Comment: For extra details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183647/how-do-i-run-katalon-test-suite-in-jenkins-inside-docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a working path for windows:

```
docker run --rm -e KATALON_OPTS="-browserType="Chrome" -retry=0 -statusDelay=15 -testSuitePath=Test\ Suites/Bla/Bla-Login/User-Pass/Login-Logout" -v /d/katalon_tests/Steptest:/katalon/katalon/source:ro -v /d/katalon_tests/Steptest/Reports:/katalon/katalon/report katalonstudio/katalon
```